# Pug span not rendering properly in a flex div

Tags: html, tags, pug

I'm using span tags to set different colors for words in a line:

CSS:

```
#some-panel{ 
display: flex; 
flex-flow: 
column wrap; 
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center; 
align-content: center; 
width: 100%; 
grid-row-start: 1;  }
```

Pug is not rendering on one single line but puts 3 breaks:

```
div#some-panel <span id="abs">Text |</span><span style="color:#b7bdc9;"> of another</span><span style="color:#ca6782;"> color</span>
```

I've also tried:

```
div#some-panel #[span text | ] #[span(style="color:#b7bdc9;") of another] #[span(style="color:#ca6782;") color]
```

but no luck.
If I delete all the flex part in my CSS, pug renders the single line correctly but I don't have a flexible div :).
What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `flex-direction` to `row` and also use `flex-wrap: nowrap` to avoid wrapping.

css:

```
#some-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

pug:

```
div#some-panel 
    span#abs Text |
    span(style="color:#b7bdc9;") of another
    span(style="color:#ca6782;") color
```

Comment: No @kmgt, it doesn't work. It's clearly some sort of conflict with flex.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See the updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot kmgt :) It's bizarre that in pure html my first version works well ... but whatever, problem solved